# How to delete NSString's text from another NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

For example:

```
NSString *sentence = @"My name is Roman";
NSString *name  = @"Roman";
```

Is there way to delete `name`'s text from `sentence` string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSString* result = [sentence stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:name withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes

```
sentence = [sentence stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:name withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `substringWithRange:` like so:

> NSString *finalString = [sentence substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 16)];

Comment: Could be an edit issue, but your answer doesn't appear to be correct. Also, though it works, this method requires you to know the range of the substring, which leads to more complex code. Are there any advantages to this more complex option?